# How to stop elastic search logging?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

i have ELK running on a server. elastic search is generating huge amount of logs in /var/log/elasticsearch folder , which results in filling my disk space quickly.I want to avoid logging for elasticsearch or want to log only error messages. 
Tried changing INFO to DEBUG , did not solve my problem.
tried with logrotation. But logger is generating logs so fast that ,it is filling 10G space in just 10 minutes.

Is there any way to get rid of this logging?
Any help ll be appreciated.thanks!

Edit:
resolved the issue. those huge amount of logs were generating because same index name was already present in the elastic server.
after deleting that index , problem is solved.

Comment: Debug would log more stuff, so that's probably not what you intended.  What is being logged?  Normally ES is pretty quiet.

Comment: yeaa , even in info level it is generating huge amount of logs.when i am running a logstash configuration, amount of data indexed by logstash is very less comapred to logs generated in /var/log/elasticsearch .  when i am opening the log files under /var/log/elasticsearch , it is showing very less info but du -km is showing more memory .

Comment: at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.onFailure(TransportNodesAction.java:205)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction.access$800(TransportNodesAction.java:107)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.nodes.TransportNodesAction$AsyncAction$2.handleException(TransportNodesAction.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:872)

Comment: it is generating such type of logs inside elasticsearch.log file in huge amount

Comment: Please mention what did you tried for changing the logging mode from DEBUG to INFO..

Comment: Looks like part of a stack trace.  You should look at the whole thing for more guidance.

Comment: Please provide one of those stack traces, as you might have other issues to resolve first.